# Root Directory in Debian (Raspberry pi)

Tags: php, adminlte

On Windows 10 I do not have an error while running AdminLTE.
But when I run AdminLTE in Debian an error occurs.

> Invalid Configuration - yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> The directory is not writable by the web process: /var/www/html/pa2/web/assets

The error is in the picture.

I hope I get a solution of this problem.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: looks like you created the folder/project with root or some other user, this is common with linux, just fix permissions so the web server can write to the directory.

Comment: Please How I can do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414009/permissions-for-var-www-html

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fix+www+folder+permissions+linux+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, we just fix the permission.

chmod -R a+rwX directory/

as root

[References](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101073/how-to-change-permissions-from-root-user-to-all-users)